# For loop "<" vs "<=" print format issues in program

Tags: c

I am learning C on my own with a book and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to solve this exercise. I'm obviously looking at it in the wrong way or something. Here is an explanation below.

Listed below are some functions and the main function at the bottom. This program is compiled to generate a certain number of random numbers and determine the min and the max of the random numbers. If you copy and paste this code, you will see how it works. Anyways, an exercise asks me to go to the function "prn_random_numbers()" and change the for loop from "for (i = 1; i < k; ++i)" to for (i = 2; i <= k; ++i). This causes the first line format to print incorrectly. The exercise is to further modify the program in the body of the for loop to get the output to be formatted correctly.

To sum it up, the "prn_random_numbers()" function is written to print out 5 random numbers before moving to the next line. Hence the" i % 5" if statement. Now, for some reason, when you make the slight adjustment to the for loop, as the exercise asks above, it causes the first line to only print 4 numbers before moving to the next line. I have tried a number of things, including trying to force it to print the 5th number, but it only duplicated one of the random numbers. I even tried "i % 4" to see if it would print 4 numbers for each row, but it only prints 3 numbers for the first row instead of 4! So it always prints one less number on the first line than it is supposed to. I have n clue why it is doing that and the book does not give an exercise. Do you have any idea?

Bear with me if you think this is a stupid question. I am just learning on my own and I want to make sure I have a good foundation and understand everything as I learn it, before moving forward. I appreciate any help or advice!

```
prn_random_numbers(k)   /* print k random numbers */
int k;
{
    int i, r, smallest, biggest;

    r = smallest = biggest = rand();
     printf("\n%12d", r);
    for (i = 1; i < k; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            printf("\n");
        r = rand();
        smallest = min(r, smallest);
        biggest = max(r, biggest);
        printf("%12d", r); 
    }
    printf("\n\n%d random numbers printed.\n", k);
    printf("Minimum:%12d\nMaximum:%12d\n", smallest, biggest);
}


int main() 
{
    int n;

    printf("Some random numbers are to be printed.\n");
    printf("How many would you like to see? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n < 1)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Please enter a positive integer.\n");
        printf("How many would you like to see? ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }        
    prn_random_numbers(n);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `r = smallest = biggest = rand();` this makes all three variables equal, is that what you want?

Comment: Try `if (i % 5 == 0)` --> `if ((i - 1)% 5 == 0)` or the like.

Comment: If your book is teaching you to define function parameters like `prn_random_numbers(k) int k; {}` then it is **ancient**. You need a better reference that's newer than 25 years old.

Comment: The posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `scanf("%d", &n);`  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Any value other than the number of input format specifiers in the format string indicates some error occurred

Comment: before calling `rand()` need to initialize the random number generator by (once only) calling `srand()`

Comment: Hi biscuit, thanks for accepting my recommendation. Good style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a debugger to solve your problem, it's easy to use and really helpfull :)

SOLUTION:
Your `i` variable don't count the number of numbers because it is initialize at 1 (in the for statement), so you need to declare a new variable to count properly.
If you have still a problem:

```
void prn_random_numbers(int k)
{
    int count = 1;
    int i, r, smallest, biggest;

    r = smallest = biggest = rand();
    printf("\n%12d", r);
    for (i = 2; i <= k; i++, count++) {
        if (count % 5 == 0) {
            count = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
        r = rand();
        smallest = min(r, smallest);
        biggest = max(r, biggest);
        printf("%12d", r); 
    }
    printf("\n\n%d random numbers printed.\n", k);
    printf("Minimum:%12d\nMaximum:%12d\n", smallest, biggest);
}
```

Comment: this posted answer will not cleanly compile because the function signature states that a `int` will be returned, but there is no `return value;` statement AND the call in the `main()` function is ignoring any returned value.  Therefore suggest the return type be changed to `void`

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. properly initializes the random number generator
2. cleanly compiles
3. properly checks for and handles errors
4. performs the desired functionality
5. avoids having to list instructions twice
6. follows the axiom: *Only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
7. does not use undefined functions like: `max()` and `min()`

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void  prn_random_numbers(int k)
{
    int count = 1;
    int r;
    int smallest;
    int biggest;

    r = smallest = biggest = rand();
    printf("\n%12d", r);
    for ( int i = 2; i <= k; i++, count++) 
    {
        if (count % 5 == 0) 
        {
            count = 0;
            printf("\n");
        }
        r = rand();
        smallest = (r < smallest)? r : smallest;
        biggest  = (r > biggest)?  r : biggest;
        printf("%12d", r); 
    }
    printf("\n\n%d random numbers printed.\n", k);
    printf("Minimum:%12d\nMaximum:%12d\n", smallest, biggest);
}



int main( void ) 
{
    int n;

    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter a positive integer, greater than 0.\n");
        printf("How many would you like to see? ");
        if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number of random numbers failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

    }  while( n < 1 );  

    prn_random_numbers(n);

    // in modern C, if the returned value from `main()` is 0 then no `return 0;` statement needed
}
```

a typical run, no input problems is:

```
Please enter a positive integer, greater than 0.
How many would you like to see? 20

    98697066  2110217332  1247184349   421403769  1643589269
  1440322693   985220171  1915371488  1920726601  1637143133
  2070012356   541419813  1708523311  1237437366  1058236022
   926434075  1422865093  2113527574   626328197  1618571881

20 random numbers printed.
Minimum:    98697066
Maximum:  2113527574
```